# How to vectorize nested for loops with numpy

Tags: python, performance, vectorization

I'm trying to stack an image and I can't wrap my head around how to make it more efficient. The following function is correct but not fast enough computationally:

```
def func(table, arr):
    img_sum = np.zeros((1024, 256))
    for i in range(1024):
        for j in range(256):
            for k in range(3):
                img_sum[i, j] += arr[int(table[i, j, k]), i, j]
    return img_sum
```

Here, *table* is shaped (1024,256,3) and *arr* is shaped (12,1024,256) and are both numpy arrays.

Is there a way to reduce the for loops to make the function more efficient?

For further clarification, I need to use the last index of the table array to stack the arr array. For example, if `table[0,0,:] = (0,1,2)`, then I need `img_sum[0,0] = arr[0,0,0]+arr[1,0,0]+arr[2,0,0]`.

So, if we have `img_sum[x,y]`, `table[x,y,j]`, and `arr[k,x,y]`, where j is 3 values from 0-11, then `img_sum[x,y] = sum(arr[j,x,y])`

Comment: what is `split_els`?

Comment: sorry that should be arr. I'll edit it

Comment: Not quite. About 10% of the values are correct using this method. I'll edit my question to provide example arrays

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a comment that worked but appears to have been deleted. The following works but seems to inadvertently round the values. However, it works for my circumstances.

`img_sum = np.take_along_axis(arr,table.transpose(2,0,1),0).sum(0)`